# MYSQL: Can't get simple SQL statement to execute correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have been using many SQL statements however for the life of me, I can't get this one to work.

I have a table called `tb_iptable`, it has two fields `uId` which is an INT and `'ipAddress` which is varchar.

The table holds the following data

```
uId  |  ipAddress
------------------
  2  | 76.76.76.76
     |
     |
```

however when is use the SQL

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_iptable WHERE uId='2' and ipAddress='76.76.76.76'"
```

but also

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_iptable WHERE ipAddress='76.76.76.76'"
```

it returns zero results.

I have no idea why this does not work, however, I may just be being stupid.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? wich one? they are diffrent DBMS.

Comment: Hi it is MySQL, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Do you have any extra white space at the end of the string in your ipAddress column? Maybe it's `'76.76.76.76 '`. If so, you should `UPDATE tb_iptable SET ipAddress=TRIM(ipAddress);` and then try the query again.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, this has seemed to work, must have put it on the table wrong multiple times woops, thanks

Answer (score 0):

use id=2 insted of id = '2'

simply don't use( ' ) around integer Id

Comment: Thanks, That is bad practice (but still works)  however this does not fix my initial problem. do you have any idea what that issue is?